# pandas dataframe plot precision

Tags: python, pandas, plot, precision

I've got a question that I haven't been able to find the answer to.

It's in regards to loading high precision csv file into pandas dataframe, and plotting.

Specifically, it appears that using pd.plot() rounds my df columns to a point where the data looks wrong when plotted.

Here is a look at the df data in question:

```
new_df[10:20]

index     Base      Base_L10  Base_L20  Base_L30
20070115  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
20070116  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
20070117  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
20070118  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
20070119  1.000843  1.000843  1.000843  1.000843
20070122  1.001520  1.001520  1.001520  1.001520
20070123  0.998745  0.998745  0.998745  0.998745
20070124  1.000558  1.000558  1.000558  1.000558
20070125  1.002821  1.002821  1.002821  1.002821
20070126  1.001801  1.001801  1.001801  1.001801
```

[image]

So that's the pandas version of a plot.

When using excel however, the plot looks like this:

[image]

Is there any good explanation/solution to this?
Thank you.

***EDIT - Clarifying Question:***

The "wrong" aspect of the df.plot() is in regards to the y-axis. It is rounding values to a point that makes the plot look jagged with flat periods. 
Whereas the excel version is able to plot the values as they are and looks much smoother.

Comment: Python is correct in terms of the x-axis - It is doing interpolation for the datetimes of your observations. If you want the graphs to appear identical use the range for your x-axis in the python plot. That is, it depends on your definition of correct.

Comment: @ScottSkiles sorry for the confusion, I edited the question. My issue is with the y axis, not the x axis.

Comment: No worries - I'm saying that your y-axis is impacted by your choice of the x-axis variable type. That is, the results are not evenly spaced on top because they are dates, whereas they ARE evenly spaced on bottom because it is simply a range of numbers. Pandas is automatically formatting the dates for you, so that the long lines are interpolating the values between your data for missing dates. It is a feature, rather than a bug.

Comment: @ScottSkiles ok now I get it! So removing the index from the df, resolved this issue BUT if we were to keep the df as it were (index is a column of dates) is there a way to fix that?

Comment: When you use pandas, it uses the index for plotting by default. You can use matplotlib and plot whatever you want. Are you ok to use matplotlib or do you need pandas plotting for some reason?

Comment: @ScottSkiles let me try matplotlib and come back if there are any questions. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I thought this was a precision error on plotting, rather than the x-axis date issue. Super helpful!